# Reading Hebrew PDF with iText 7 get Gibrish

Tags: .net, pdf, itext, itext7

I am trying to read a Hebrew PDF, but I am getting Gibrish instead.

I am using the code @mkl gave me a year ago when I had a similar problem, as described below, but unfortunately, it is not working.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= pdfDocument.GetNumberOfPages(); i++) {
  PdfPage page1 = pdfDocument.GetPage(i);
  PdfDictionary fontResources = page1.GetResources().GetResource(PdfName.Font);
  foreach (PdfObject font in fontResources.Values(true))
  {
    if (font is PdfDictionary fontDict)
        fontDict.Put(PdfName.Encoding, PdfName.IdentityH);
  }
  // get page size
  Rectangle pageSize = pdfDocument.GetPage(i).GetMediaBox();
  float pageHeight = pageSize.GetHeight();
  float pageWidth = pageSize.GetWidth();

  // set location
  Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, pageWidth, pageHeight);
  TextRegionEventFilter regionFilter = new TextRegionEventFilter(rect);
                    
  ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new FilteredTextEventListener(new LocationTextExtractionStrategy(), regionFilter);
  inputStr = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(page1, strategy);

  // rest of code...
}
```

The output (inputStr) is total gibrish:

```
�����������\n��������\n������ �����������������\n���\n�����������\n����������������\n��������������������������� ������\n���\n���������\n��������������������������\n����������������������\n�������
```

Since the PDF has sensitive data, I can't really share it publicly...

Appreciate your help,
Yaniv

Comment: Most likely the pdf does not contain the information required for regular text extraction. Without an analysis of the pdf there is no way to help seriously.

Comment: @mkl unfortunately, I can't share the pdf publicly. can I sent it over privately for you to take a look? Appreciate the help.

Comment: BTW, I am able to copy/paste some of the content. other content is copied as nonsense... at this point I am good with extract the text that is going thru the copy/paste without issues. The point is - I can't the entire page looks like nonsense...

Comment: You can send it to the email address mentioned in my profile here.

Comment: @mkl, I sent it to your email. Really appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: A first look at your file shows that the **ToUnicode** CMap for all the fonts in the PDF is broken, or more exactly it may be ok as a CMap in general but it contains entries not allowed in **ToUnicode** CMaps. Apparently Adobe Acrobat handles these invalid CMaps differently than iText 7, allowing Acrobat to extract some text as desired. I'll try and look into details later this week.

Comment: @mkl, thanks. Waiting for your input. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of this issue are invalid **ToUnicode** CMaps for all the fonts in the PDF: These CMaps may be valid for other uses but in the context of **ToUnicode** CMaps the PDF specification clearly restricts the data which may occur in this kind of CMap.

One can enable iText, though, to make sense out of this by a small patch.

## The problem

The **ToUnicode** CMaps in the document are invalid in particular as they use **begincidrange** ... **endcidrange** sections for mapping the character codes instead of **beginbfrange** ... **endbfrange** and **beginbfchar** ... **endbfchar** sections as required here by the specification.

By chance iText does process **~cidrange** sections in **ToUnicode** CMaps just like **~bfrange** sections. (Well, not really by chance but because the class for processing **ToUnicode** CMaps extends an abstract base class for processing arbitrary CMaps.)

Unfortunately, though, **~cidrange** ranges have an integer destination start value (e.g. `<0003> <0003> 32`) while **~bfrange** ranges in **ToUnicode** CMaps must have hex string destination start values (e.g. `<0000><005E><0020>`). As a result parsing these **ToUnicode** CMaps with **~cidrange** ranges in iText fails with an exception, leaving behind a map without entries. The result is that none of the character codes in the document can be mapped to anything sensible and all text is extracted as replacement characters ('�').

## A work-around

An obvious approach to fix this is by enabling the code processing the ranges to also handle integer destination start values, not only hex string values.

With that fix applied most of the characters can be extracted properly. You merely have to deal with the wrong order of RTL script text.

*(I tested only the Java version but the .Net version should work, too.)*

#### Java

In the `com.itextpdf.io.font.cmap.CMapToUnicode` class (`com.itextpdf.io` artifact) the following method is called to add mappings derived from ranges:

```java
@Override
void addChar(String mark, CMapObject code) {
    if (mark.length() == 1) {
        char[] dest = createCharsFromDoubleBytes((byte[]) code.getValue());
        byteMappings.put((int) mark.charAt(0), dest);
    } else if (mark.length() == 2) {
        char[] dest = createCharsFromDoubleBytes((byte[]) code.getValue());
        byteMappings.put((mark.charAt(0) << 8) + mark.charAt(1), dest);
    } else {
        Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CMapToUnicode.class);
        logger.warn(LogMessageConstant.TOUNICODE_CMAP_MORE_THAN_2_BYTES_NOT_SUPPORTED);
    }
}
```

Here `code.getValue()` without any test is cast to `byte[]` as that's how hex strings are represented here. Integer values in contrast would be represented as `Integer` instances. Thus, the

```java
char[] dest = createCharsFromDoubleBytes((byte[]) code.getValue());
```

lines have to be replaced by

```java
char[] dest = (code.getValue() instanceof Integer) ? TextUtil.convertFromUtf32((Integer)code.getValue()) : createCharsFromDoubleBytes((byte[]) code.getValue());
```

lines.

#### .Net

In the `iText.IO.Font.Cmap.CMapToUnicode` class (`itext.io.netstandard` assembly) the following method is called to add mappings derived from ranges:

```c#
internal override void AddChar(String mark, CMapObject code) {
    if (mark.Length == 1) {
        char[] dest = CreateCharsFromDoubleBytes((byte[])code.GetValue());
        byteMappings.Put((int)mark[0], dest);
    }
    else {
        if (mark.Length == 2) {
            char[] dest = CreateCharsFromDoubleBytes((byte[])code.GetValue());
            byteMappings.Put((mark[0] << 8) + mark[1], dest);
        }
        else {
            ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(iText.IO.Font.Cmap.CMapToUnicode));
            logger.Warn(iText.IO.LogMessageConstant.TOUNICODE_CMAP_MORE_THAN_2_BYTES_NOT_SUPPORTED);
        }
    }
}
```

Here `code.GetValue()` without any test is cast to `byte[]` as that's how hex strings are represented here. Integer values in contrast would be represented as `int` instances.
Like in the Java case, therefore, it should suffice to replace the

```c#
char[] dest = CreateCharsFromDoubleBytes((byte[])code.GetValue());
```

lines by

```c#
char[] dest = (code.GetValue() is int) ? TextUtil.ConvertFromUtf32((int)code.GetValue()) : CreateCharsFromDoubleBytes((byte[])code.GetValue());
```

lines.

Comment: Hey @mkl, thanks for your answer. I am using .NET CORE with iText 7.1.4. Not sure what I need to do with the code you wrote. I mean, I can find the class CMapToUnicode, but it doesn't have any AddChar method, not I can edit it. What exactly should I do in my code to apply the workaround? Thanks

Comment: *"I can find the class CMapToUnicode, but it doesn't have any AddChar method"* - That is incorrect as you can see in the itext7-dotnet sources [here](https://github.com/itext/itext7-dotnet/blob/7.1.4/itext/itext.io/itext/io/font/cmap/CMapToUnicode.cs#L152). *"What exactly should I do"* - you should check out the itext sources, apply the change, build itext and use your built. Itext is open source after all!  Alternatively, ask itext support to integrate that change in the mainstream itext code.